# Jenkins Groovy function not being CPS transformed because of the use of Jenkins API

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following test function:

```
def doSomething() {
    def node = Jenkins.get().getNode("node-name")
    def count = 0
    retry (5) {
        println "hello"
        count += 1
        if (count < 3) {
            throw new InterruptedException()
        }
    }
}
```

that is called from a pipeline step e.g.:

```
stage(..) {
  steps {
    script {
      doSomething()
    }

  }
}
```

But I get a CPS serialization exception:

```
 an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5e799cd4
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@e7332c3
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@4fed11ca
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@74cb9088
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@74cb9088
 Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.Hudson
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:274)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
...
```

as soon as I remove the line `def node = Jenkins.get().getNode..` the exception goes away.

Is this happening because Jenkins API is not callable from CPS code and if so why ?

Comment: Would annotating as `NonCPS` otherwise break the functionality?

Comment: Yes it would because then I wouldn't be able to use the "retry" pipeline step as pipeline steps aren't allowed in NonCPS code

Answer (score 0):

Pass the node to the function from the Pipeline.

```
def doSomething(def node) {
    def count = 0
    retry (5) {
        println "hello"
        count += 1
        if (count < 3) {
            throw new InterruptedException()
        }
    }
}
```

```
stage(..) {
  steps {
    script {
      doSomething(Jenkins.get().getNode("node-name"))
    }

  }
}
```